# DOMPDF gives an error in "render" method. Something wrong with fonts. How can I fix it?

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, dompdf

I am experiencing a problem.
Dompdf gives such an error when I call "render" method on the dompdf object:

Uncaught DOMPDF_Exception: Unable to find a suitable font replacement for: 'serif'

My html document contains hebrew symbols, but I also tried to test the code only with english symbols. Same result.

The HTML that I try to render is big, and I have specified the sans-serif font family in document's CSS. I am using version 0.8.3

Some code:

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $contentPdf = '<p>hello world</p>';
    $dompdf->load_html($contentPdf);
    $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
```

What can be wrong? Should I try to use older version?
Thanks.

Comment: Can please you add minimal code?

Comment: @PramodMali thank you for your attention. I have added something...